# How to fix this broken access control issue in a web application?

Tags: owasp-top-ten

Say the URL of the site in
http://www.example.com

The affected URL is:

- http://www.example.com/admin/doAdminStuffs_1.html
- http://www.example.com/admin/doAdminStuffs_2.html

Say there are two types of users on the example website, "producers" and "consumer".

A consumer is able to access the site by putting a header/URL called `link=doAdminStuffs_1`
How to fix this issue?

The obvious answer is to not let consumer to add extra headers?

Comment: ... anyone can add to a URL and send it. The obvious solution from OWASP, that you linked, is to *authenticate* to allow actions...

Comment: ok should i delete this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup authentication in order to assign a role to the user.  Then, use that role to authorize access by role to certain frontend routes. When a user tries to access a uri they are not permitted to access, do something like route them to login, or do nothing.  Implementing all this is big scope.  Similar concept for API.
Here is a SO article about protected routes in react.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou